# How to implement callback function in NPAPI Plugin

Tags: npapi, browser-plugin

I am developing NPAPI Plugin for embedded native browser (Linux) . I want one callback function from javascript that will invoke callback function in my plugin . As per the events generated by pressing the keys of keyboard . I have to  send events continously to the browser window. I am completely new to this  needs help .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using FireBreath, the [documentation on firing events](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Firing+Events+from+JSAPI) already covers this.

If you are writing a plain NPAPI plugin, your plugin should implement [`addEventListener(type, listener, ...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) & [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener).
As you already know how to add scriptable functions to your plugin, you just need to add support for these two.

For **`addEventListener()`** you get the following arguments:

- `type` - should be a string that identifies the event
- `listener` - should be an object, retain & store it
- `useCapture` - should be a boolean, optional, if not present assume `false`

To store the listeners you could e.g. use a [`multimap<SomeStringType,NPObject*>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/) member, with the event string as your key and the listener object as the value. Don't forget to [retain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_RetainObject) the listener.

To **fire an event** you then get the [`equal_range()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/equal_range/) for it and use [`NPN_InvokeDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_InvokeDefault) with the listener objects.

**`removeEventListener()`** receives the same arguments as `addEventListener()` and you should then [`erase()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/erase/) the specified listener for that event string. Don't forget to [release](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_ReleaseObject) the listener object.

*To honor `useCapture` extend the above accordingly.*

Comment: I am using plain NPAPI , can u please explain by example . How to add event listener and fire default method of all stored listener NPN_InvokeDefault().  If possible any link to refer . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @r_tex, have you read [this tutorial on providing interfaces to JS](http://colonelpanic.net/2009/08/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-three/)?

Comment: Thanks , For the link Yes i have gone through this link, and implemented already working plugin where i am able to call plugin methods from javascript. Flow is as follows -> Created one class ScriptablePluginObjectBase derived from NPObject, then Created one class ScriptablePluginObject derived from ScriptablePluginObjectBase, Inside ScriptablePluginObject's invoke method i am calling methods that r called from javascript. Sorry i am new to this , can u please tell me how to write addEventListener, removeEventListener and add/remove the listener parameter(NP Object) to/from a per-type list.

Comment: Okk I got it , how to do it .